# What could cause this generator expression to be corrupted?

Tags: python, ipython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python builtin “all” with generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491951/python-builtin-all-with-generators)

I've come across the following reproducible behaviour in IPython:

```
def test(lst):
    for val in (v is not None for v in lst):
        print val
    print all(v is not None for v in lst)
    print
    print [v is not None for v in lst]
    print all([v is not None for v in lst])
    print
    print
    for val in (v is None for v in lst):
        print val
    print all(v is None for v in lst)
    print
    print [v is None for v in lst]
    print all([v is None for v in lst])

>>> test([1])
True
True

[True]
True

False
True

[False]
False
```

The error originally appeared in the midst of a much larger algorithm, but it reduces to the above test case.

Now this output is clearly wrong, but I've got no idea what's going on.  If I repeat in the standard python shell, it gives the expected output.

### Additional Notes

The third set of print statements show the error: 
`all(v is None for v in [1])` should return **True**, not False.

IPython is running with a lot of objects loaded (about 1.5GB worth, most below one parent object).  If I close everything and restart, the error disappears, but it reappears if reload my data.

My thought is that there must be some memory corruption going on, but I'm stumped as to what it could be.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here's what I believe he's seeing: `all(v is None for v in lst) != all([v is None for v in lst])`.

Comment: In the third case, if you iterate through the generator, the only item is False.  However, all(generator) is True

Comment: @sapi Ah, I see - I was looking at my results and not yours, apologies :)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the system `all`? Or has it been overwritten by anything? Perhaps by numpy?

Comment: `numpy.all` do not iterate on generators... try using `__builtin__.all`

Comment: Aha - you guys have it, thanks a heap :)  I didn't realise that IPython was pulling in the numpy all.  It didn't occur to me that it would replace builtins!  (I've always thought it a weird choice that they've cluttered the global namespace with so much junk, but I didn't realise they'd overwrite things)

Comment: they don't pollute the global namespace for you, you pollute your global namespace by `from numpy import *`.  don't do that.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - I never do that, which is why this caught me by surprise.  It must be an IPython default for the qtconsole (with inlined pylab).

Comment: ah.. yes, it looks like `pylab` imports "core parts of numpy, scypy and matplotlib" (http://www.scipy.org/PyLab)