# PythonXY, spyder and python any() function

Tags: python, string, numpy, any, spyder

I'm trying to search words in a text with the function `any()` of python, I was expecting the same behaviour for the two following, but it's not:

```
keyword_list=['WASHER', 'SCREW']
all_text  = "test_string"
if any(word in all_text for word in keyword_list):
    print "some of the strings found in str"
else:
    print "no strings found in str"

if (True in (word in all_text for word in keyword_list)):
    print "some of the strings found in str"
else:
    print "no strings found in str"
```

running inside Spyder 2.2.0 with python 2.7.5(I downloaded the pythonXY package) the results are different from launching python with normal cmd console.

In fact result inside Spyder:

```
>>> runfile(r'C:\untitled0.py', wdir=r'C:\PythonTestbench')
some of the strings found in str
no strings found in str
```

In fact result inside command prompt:

```
>>> runfile(r'C:\untitled0.py', wdir=r'C:\PythonTestbench')
no strings found in str
no strings found in str
```

Has Spyder environment has another version of `any()` function, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493265/487339).

How can I force to not use the function contained into NumPy?

Comment: Both versions print `no strings found in str`. What's wrong?

Comment: Both yield False—What is your issue?

Comment: works for me, also if I change 'SCREW' into 'string' so they return True

Comment: Hey, I can reproduce this behaviour. Found it for python version 2.7.3 in IPython Notebook, oddly it works in the IPython shell. On another computer I am having Python version 2.7.5 and there it is working either way. @tinix84 How did you run your code?

Comment: I modified above with a better explanation, thanks guys

Comment: Okay - probably not the answer you're looking for, but see this [bug report on github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2598/). Maybe your any() function has been replaced as well... @tinix84 What is the output if you run `print any`? it should be `<built-in function any>`...

Comment: Yeah, this is because PythonXY imports numpy's `all` and `any` into scope, clobbering the builtins.  See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493265/487339).

Comment: @asPlankBridge my printout of any is : <function any at 0x033915B0>

Comment: Okay, I get a similar output for the numpy any variant. If it is numpy the output of `print help(any)` should mention `module numpy.core.fromnumeric` in the first line. One solution is to use `__builtin__.any()` or write at the top of your script `from __builtin__ import any` or use another Editor. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code in this way:

```
keyword_list=['WASHER', 'SCREW']
all_text  = "test_string"
print any # so we can see where it comes from
mkgen = lambda: (word in all_text for word in keyword_list)
print list(mkgen()) # to see what we have

if any(mkgen()):
    print "any: some of the strings found in str"
else:
    print "any: no strings found in str"

if (True in mkgen()):
    print "in: some of the strings found in str"
else:
    print "in: no strings found in str"
```

This program makes it apparent what happens:

- it prints out the nature of `any` so you see if it is the "normal one" or a version overwritten by some `import *`
- it as well prints out the boolean values generated

If you have managed to find out what's wrong, please use the `any()` variant. It is much more pythonic.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't change my final result: the printout is `[False, False]
any: some of the strings found in str
in: no strings found in str`

Comment: @tinix84 You are missing the first line of the printout: what does `print any` give? This is essential, as t shows us if it comes from Python itself or from a 3rd party module.

Comment: my printout of any is : <function any at 0x033915B0>